# Refetch queries with any combination of parameters

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have faced with a problem when refetching queries after mutation. If query has no parameters thats ok, but if query has several parameters, and different pages uses different of them. For example, GET_ITEMS query accepts parameters: userId, companyId, categoryId. How can I say to Apollo to refetch all this queries with any combination of parameters?

Answer (score 0):

It seem there is no way I can make it now with Apollo Client. So I had to save the parameters of all GET_ITEMS calls from all pages, and then transfer the saved parameters to the refetchQueries mutation method. The code turned out like this:

ItemsContext.js

```
const ItemsContext = React.createContext({
  cachedQueryVars: [],
});
```

ItemsList.js

```
...
render() {
...
return <ItemsContext.Consumer>{({cachedQueryVars}) => {
       cachedQueryVars.push(variables);
       return <Query query={GET_ITEMS} variables={variables} >
...
```

ItemEdit.js

```
...
render() {
...
return <ItemsContext.Consumer>{({cachedQueryVars}) => 
              <Mutation mutation={UPDATE_ITEM_MUTATION}
                  refetchQueries={({data}) => this.handleRefetchQueries(data.updateItem, cachedQueryVars)}
...
}

handleRefetchQueries(newItem, cachedItemsQueryVars) {
  let result = [];
  let filtered = null;

  if(this.state.oldCategoryId != newItem.category.id) {
    filtered = cachedItemsQueryVars.filter(v => v.categoryId == this.state.oldCategoryId);
    result = this.concatItemQueryVars(result, filtered);
    filtered = cachedItemsQueryVars.filter(v => v.categoryId == newItem.category.id);
    result = this.concatItemQueryVars(result, filtered);
  }
  if(this.state.oldCompanyId != newItem.company.id) {
    filtered = cachedItemsQueryVars.filter(v => v.companyId == this.state.oldCompanyId);
    result = this.concatItemQueryVars(result, filtered);
    filtered = cachedItemsQueryVars.filter(v => v.companyId == newItem.company.id);
    result = this.concatItemQueryVars(result, filtered);
  }
  ...

  return result;
}

concatItemQueryVars(result, filtered) {
  return result.concat(filtered.map(v => ({
    query: GET_ITEMS,
    variables: v
  })));
}
```